# Is it possible to update multiple list items with a workflow?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a list which contains a value that I would like copied to all items in another list that share the same "Owner" field. This works with the Update List Item action if I set it to match Owner(List1):Owner(List2), but it only runs on the first item.

Edit: Related issue is that I seem to be able to match items in another list based on text fields, but not people fields. When I select a name field, it doesn't give me an option to select what I'm returning it as but I can set what to compare the matching value to.

Example: 
[image]

The first Modified By simply allows you to select it from the other list (without specifying its return type), but the second Modified By which matches it to my current list has me choose several options. None of these comparisons seem to work, and I'm not sure how to see what the first Modified By is being saved (by logging it) in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior: in SP 2010, the query only returns the first item.

To update multiple items, you'll have to resort to tricks, for example add a column that serves as a flag once an item is updated. Another option is to attach the workflow to the second list (the one with the Owner field).

This has been addressed in SP 2013 (kind of...) where you can create workflow loops.

Comment: Believe I'll put it on the second list as you've  suggested since I might not be able to get a 2013 site in time. Thanks! My only issue now is that comparing people fields doesn't seem to be working. I've updated my answer with more information if that'd be useful.

Comment: Usually matching by login or e-mail address will work.

Comment: That's freaking stupid.  I HATE SharePoint.  HATE it.  I'm thinking about removing it from my resume and just flat-out refusing to ever look at it again.

Comment: @Hill for the record we are talking about a version of SharePoint that is 6 years old. Things are different in SP 2013, SP2016 and SP Online.

Comment: I hope so.  My office is still on SharePoint 2010.  They have a migration coming in a month to 2013, so we're HOPING (but not holding our breath) that SP has somewhat gotten its act together.

Comment: @Hill that's good news, unfortunately that's still 3 years behind. Microsoft is really stepping up the game this year with Microsoft Flow and PowerApps that address this kind of requirement.

Comment: Wait... so SharePoint still doesn't address this kind of requirement?  Because, I'm trying to figure out if, in SharePoint 2013, if we WILL be able to do this without any kind of witchcraft.  Namely, I'm trying to make it so that, if you select multiple items in a view, if you can edit ALL of those items at once.

Comment: @Hill it does address the OP's requirement, see my answer. I was just saying that we now have more options. Your requirement is a different question.

Comment: @Christophe - Sorry... I forgot my secret StackExchange decoder ring at home today, so I wasn't exactly sure where to say what.

Answer (score 2):

No, not in 2010. Workflow products like Nintex and K2 give you that functionality at a price though. Alternatively, you could use web services to bulk update information. The [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateListItems&referringTitle=Lists) library has a great wrapper to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for a while.  SPServices as a library of Javascript working with jQuery worked for my needs.  It does bulk updates to list and libraries.

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems